How to extract (as a dataframe) columns from a dataframe where all other row entries of a given column are NA?
I am trying to extract columns or subset a dataframe based on the condition of NA. Here is an example. I am looking for a generalized solution that could work for a greater number of TV types and colors. The number of TV types would be known beforehand and stored in a variable. In this case, 4.
I have the following dataframe where column 1 "colors" contains row labels/titles:
my_data <- data.frame(
  colors = c("Blue", "Red", "Green"),
  OLED = c(50, 45, NA),
  OLED2 = c(NA, 40, NA),
  LCD = c(NA, 40, NA),
  CRT = c(NA, 50, 45)
)

I want to apply the following to each TV type (OLED, OLED2, LCD, CRT). The following code applies to the solution for CRT:
a = my_data[is.na(my_data$OLED) & is.na(my_data$OLED2) & is.na(my_data$LCD),]


Is there a more elegant and efficient way to extract rows of a given column where all other row values are NA? The output for this example would ideally be two dataframes, one with the CRT information and another with OLED information since only those columns contain rows where all other rows are NA (except for the first column, which is more of a label for the rows). Is a loop the only option here?

You could use lapply here with filter from dplyr:
library(dplyr)

setNames(
  lapply(names(my_data[,-1]), \(x) 
      filter(my_data, if_all(setdiff(names(my_data[,-1]), x), ~is.na(.)))),
  names(my_data[,-1]))

Which gives a list for each TV type:
$OLED
  colors OLED OLED2 LCD CRT
1   Blue   50    NA  NA  NA

$OLED2
[1] colors OLED   OLED2  LCD    CRT   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$LCD
[1] colors OLED   OLED2  LCD    CRT   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$CRT
  colors OLED OLED2 LCD CRT
1  Green   NA    NA  NA  45


my_data[rowSums(!is.na(my_data[-1])) == 1,]|>
   (\(x)split(x,rownames(x)))()

$`1`
  colors OLED OLED2 LCD CRT
1   Blue   50    NA  NA  NA

$`3`
  colors OLED OLED2 LCD CRT
3  Green   NA    NA  NA  45


my_data[rowSums(!is.na(my_data[-1])) == 1,] -> x
split(x, rownames(x))

$`1`
  colors OLED OLED2 LCD CRT
1   Blue   50    NA  NA  NA

$`3`
  colors OLED OLED2 LCD CRT
3  Green   NA    NA  NA  45


I like that creative use of the inline function to appease the native pipe |>. I'll put that in my back pocket next time I don't feel like firing up dplyr for its %>%
